# Detecting when an element is refreshed, even if the value doesn't change

Tags: python, selenium

(Selenium/webscraping noob warning.)

```
selenium 3.141.0
chromedriver 78
MacOS 10.14.6
```

I'm compiling a list of URLs across a range of dates for later download. The URLs are in a table that displays information for the date selected on a nearby calendar. When the user clicks a new date on the calendar, the table is updated asynchronously with a new list of URLs or – if no files exist for that date – with a message inside a `<td class="dataTables_empty">` tag.

For each date in the desired range, my code clicks the calendar, using `WebDriverWait` with a custom `expectation` to track when the first `href` value in the table changes (indicating the table has finished updating), and scrapes the URLs for that day. If no files are available for a given date, the code looks for the `dataTables_empty` tag to go away to indicate the next date's URLs have loaded.

```py
if current_first_uri != NO_ATT_DATA:
    element = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until_not(
                  text_to_be_present_in_href((
                      By.XPATH, first_uri_in_att_xpath), 
                                current_first_uri))
else:
    element = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until_not(
                  EC.presence_of_element_located((
                      By.CLASS_NAME, "dataTables_empty")))
```

This works great in all my use cases but one: if two or more consecutive days have no data, the code doesn't notice the table has refreshed, since the `dataTables_empty` class remains in the table (and the cell is identical in every other respect).

In the Chrome inspector, when I click from one date without data to another, the corresponding `<td>` flashes pink. That suggests the values are being updated, even though their values remain the same.

**Questions:**

- Is there a mechanism in Selenium to detect that the value was *refreshed*, even if it hasn't *changed*?
- If not, any creative ideas on how to determine the table has refreshed in the problem use case? I don't want to wait blindly for some arbitrary length of time.

**UPDATE:** *The accepted answer answered the latter of the two questions, and I was able to replace my entire detection scheme using the MutationObserver.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a MutationObserver:

```
driver.execute_script("""
  new MutationObserver(() => {
    window.lastRefresh = new Date()
  }).observe(document.querySelector('table.my-table'), { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true } )
""")
```

And get the last time the table dom changed with:

```
lastRefresh = driver.execute_script("return window.lastRefresh")
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this below method to check if element has gone stale or not. Usually expecting false.

The same may help in your case when you are expecting true.

```
isElementStale(driver, element) {
    try:
        wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 2)
        element.isEnabled()
        element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(element))
        if element != null:
            return False
    except:
         print('')
    return True
}
```

So you can pass element to this method and check if any change has occured to it like

```
# element = Get First element
# Make changes that causes the refresh
if (isElementStale(driver, element)):
    print('Element refreshed')
else:
    print('Element Not refreshed')
```